# Where is the aspnet_setreg located in windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows-7

Does anyone know where to find aspnet_setreg  in a windows 7 machine? I checked these folders and couldn't find it there

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

Comment: It appears to be [supplied as a downloadable package](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329290) (at least from 2003).. no idea what products it was distributed with. (Although isn't this primarily for weaknesses in ASP 1.x?)

Comment: I just need a tool to add values to registry. I remember aspnet_setreg being easy to use. Are there any other?

Comment: Take a tool at the ["reg" tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643%28v=ws.10%29) for this purpose.